# Stop float DIVs from wrapping without knowing the width of the containing div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/4HQgj/

So, most of what's there aside, I am looking to, inside #wrapper, have many columns.  In each column I have bubbles, and sub bubbles(or note bubbles).  Each column is currently `float:left;`.  The problem I am having, the columns wrap when I resize it too thinly.  What I am looking to make happen, is for the #wrapper div to detect it and add scrollbars instead of wrapping the columns.

I have seen that setting a width to #wrapper is possible, but I don't want to do this, as it would force a scrollbar when I didn't need it.  Also, the columns can be different widths, and I want the wrapper to scroll only when all columns aren't entirely viewable.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/c3xLg/)

```
var wWidth = 0;
$(".column").each(function(){
   /* Get the width of the columns including their margins */
   wWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});
/* Set the wrapper's width to this value */
$("#wrapper").width(wWidth);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid a scripted option, but there is no denying that this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `min-width` to prevent the `#wrapper` from getting smaller than a specific width, at which point scrollbars would be introduced. This will allow your layout to flow to accommodate more content until the browser window reduces to a certain size.

[More information on min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

Comment: This would only help if I were to assume the columns didn't go past that width, combined, which sadly I cannot.  My aim is to allow infinite columns, theoretically.